# How to show date value in another format (python date to text) on worksheet

Tags: python, google-apps-script, google-sheets, google-sheets-api

I am using the Google Sheets API for inserting some data on my sheet.
Every row has a date cell that has values in this format **"2017-02-01 19:33:56+00:00"** I would like it to display it in this format **(02 January 2017)** but I would like to have the original format hidden on the same cell.

> Is there a script or something that I can use to display the date in that format?

Comment: @TheMaster done sir, sorry i am new on the site

Answer (score 1):

Just add a custom numberformat from the format menu. This one should do the trick "dd MMM yyyy".  The date doesn't change so if you want to go back to the old one you always can.  You can use a script to switch between them using [range.setNumberFormat](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/range#setNumberFormat(String))

You can use this script to setNumberFormats():

```
SpreadsheetApp.getActiveRange().setNumberFormat("dd MMM yyyy");
```

I not familiar with the ss+00:00 not sure what that means. But perhaps you can checked the documentation below.  You might be able to use [range.getNumberFormat()](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/range#getNumberFormat()) to get and save that format for future use.

```
var formatString=SpreadsheetApp.getActiveRange().getNumberFormat();
```

- [Number Formats Documentation](https://developers.google.com/sheets/api/guides/formats)

Comment: Thank you so much! very helpfull your reply. I think +00:00 is the timezone of the datetime value. I will use that for setting the time into my timezone.

Comment: I suggest not accepting this answer and waiting for one of the more senior volunteers to sweep down and provide us both with a greater sampling of wisdom on this matter.

Comment: So is your timezone "GMT"?

Comment: my timezone is GMT (-4) but the date in my code is UTC. So i made a simple code for getting it in my time using this "timedelta(hours=-4)" . But i have to split the data into an array first for deleting that final variable on the date, then i have to convert it to my timezone using that function. But it would be nice using an specific formatting for that it should exist. Like for example this "datetime.strptime('1/25/2019 18:10:11', '%m/%d/%Y %H:%M:%S')" but using that timezone on data. I cant find that here https://docs.python.org/2/library/datetime.html#strftime-and-strptime-behavior

Comment: so then i can convert that to my timezone in an easier way

Answer (score 1):

This format **"2017-02-01 19:33:56+00:00"** is not being recognized for Google Sheets, it's because it has an additional value to the final that indicates the timezone of the date **"+00:00"**, i decided to create an small script for getting ride of that timezone value and also add/sub hours and minutes to the date so i can see the correct hour in my timezone.

```
from datetime import datetime, timedelta

def formatDatetime(o_date, f_hours=0, f_minutes=0):
    # ----- Removing the timezone from the data str
    date_a = o_date.split('+')
    date = date_a[0]
    #----------------------------------------------------
    # ----- Format/Add/Sub Hours and minutes
    date = datetime.strptime(date, '%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S')
    date = date + timedelta(hours=f_hours)
    date = date + timedelta(minutes=f_minutes)
    date_f = format(date, '%m/%d/%Y %H:%M:%S')
    # -------------------
    return date_f
```

Now google sheet recognizes this value as a date, so i can make a custom formatting for showing a nice date in my worksheet.